# Loop to draw a piece on a grid

Tags: java, swing

I have a 640x640 grid that maps to an 8x8 2D array. I need to be able to draw an oval in the place that the user clicks and I'm trying to figure out a loop to do it instead of typing multiple if statements.

For example I can write this for each square on the board and it will draw the desired shape with no issue.

```
oldx = event.getX(); 
oldy = event.getY(); 
if(oldx<=80&&oldy<=80){
board[0][0]=1; 
    repaint();
```

}

I'm trying to make a loop and this is what I have so far, it is not working out well though. It prints in undesired locations. I think the way I have it here is that it only prints in locations that are divisible by 80. I need to take in the x and y coordinates to the 2D array.

```
    int x1 = oldx/80;
    int y1 = oldy/80;
    for(int r=0; r<8; r++){
      for(int c=0; c<8; c++){
          board[x1][y1] = 1;
           repaint();
         }  
       }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please expand on "not working well" means.  If you could show more than one cell of your old hardcoded way that might help explain it better.

Comment: Doing some edits now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem like you are on the right path.  However, you don't have your condition in the loop example.  You need to add an `if()` statement inside your double `for` loop to check to see if the selected X and Y match the current square you are looping through.

Comment: I have added a tried the following if statement earlier and it was giving no output.  if(oldx<=x1&&oldy<=y1)

Comment: I think you should be comparing x1 to r and y1 to c.

Comment: So what happens now, I click a square and a piece appears on another square. I'm close but not close enough. I did the comparison that you have stated above.

Comment: Your dealing with an index that is zero based on the array, but might not be in your caluclation.   Therefore you most likely will either need to compare `x1 -1` to `c` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

This will get it working for you.

```
    boolean found = false;
    while(found!=true){
    for(int r=0; r<8; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<8; c++){
        if(y1==c&&x1==r){
            board[r][c] = 1;
            found = true;
            repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```